# $Cov(X, e) =0$ implies $Cov(X^{2}, e) = 0$?

Tags: regression, econometrics, covariance

In regression analysis where we assume that $E(e|X) = 0$, I wish to understand whether the implication in the title holds true. I understand that
$Cov(X, e) = Cov(X, E(e|X))$
But is it true that if $E(e|X) = 0$ then $E(e|X^{2}) = 0$?
Because if that is the case then the result is straightforward.
Please help me understand if I'm missing some important point here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query, let $Y=g(X)$ be a deterministic function of $X$, using the law of iterated expectation, we have
$$\mathbb E[e|Y]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[e|X,Y]|Y]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[e|X,g(X)]|g(X)]$$
It's obvious that $\mathbb E[e|X,g(X)]=\mathbb E[e|X]=0$. So, the expected value above becomes
$$\mathbb E[e|Y] = \mathbb E[0|g(X)]=0$$
Whether $g(X)$ is $X^2$ or not is not relevant here.

About the covariance, another way to see it is
$$\operatorname{cov}(X^2,e)=\mathbb E[X^2e]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X^2e|X]]=\mathbb E[X^2\mathbb E[e|X]]=0$$